# What would cause a LBC-managed region access to hang?

Tags: embedded, powerpc

I'm trying to write a Compact Flash driver for the RouterBoard 800, for FreeBSD, and running into problems.  The CF slot is managed by the Local Bus Controller (LBC) of the CPU (MPC8544E), using the User Programmable Machine (UPM) module and any access to the memory region the CF is located at hangs the thread (the CPU can still be interrupted, but the thread never continues).  Even dummy accesses, when programming or reading the UPM, hang.  Now, the question is, what would cause the thread to hang when accessing the UPM-managed region, even if it's a dummy access, which should not actually assert the bus?

I know the CF card and slot themselves work, because the kernel itself boots from the card, loaded by the RouterBoard boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the mpc8544E (probably most of the mpc85xx series) has the concept of Local Access Windows (LAWs).  If an address does not exist in any of the 10 windows created, it's dropped on the floor, with no exception thrown nor garbage data returned.  This is true for all address regions, including external RAM.